# Is there a better pattern for implementing a class that uses profilebase?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

So testing in MVC is a pain the butt because of all of MS's Stupid static methods but I have been able to work around some of it - I created a Interface for membership so that I can mock it and that mostly works but I am using ProfileBase in my custom UserProfile object and that is of course a lot harder because it too has static methods and it inherits from ProfileBase. I have wasted my entire Sunday and can't figure out how to test this.

Here is what my UserPofile class looks like - it is really just the same as all the examples online.

```
namespace TaskBoardAuth.Models
{
    public class UserProfile: ProfileBase
    {
        public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
        {
            return Create(username) as UserProfile;
        }

        public static UserProfile GetUserProfile()
        {
            return Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName) as UserProfile;
        }

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return base["FirstName"] as string; }
            set { base["FirstName"] = value; }
        }

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return base["LastName"] as string; }
            set { base["LastName"] = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Problem is I can't test because of those two stupid crappy static methods, never mind that profileBase.Create() is static. ERR! That so asinine!

Anyway - Here is where I am stuck - I need to do this in a method.

```
taskBoardModel.Name = UserProfile.GetUserProfile().FirstName + " " + UserProfile.GetUserProfile().LastName;
```

My unit test of course blows up because the call to Membership.GetUser() fails! Err!!!

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with any framework problems such as this MVC one, I generally create a wrapper class and an accompanying interface around the internal classes that I may need to test/mock. I then configure my IoC container to inject into the controller's constructor my IUserProfile interface. So in my unit tests, I simply mock my IUserProfile and provide whatever data I want.

The Membership.GetUser() issue can be solved the same way by creating a wrapper class and interface.

I used to worry about problems like this, but now I don't even sweat it and just create wrapper classes around any of .NET's crazy sealed classes and static methods and so forth.

Comment: Hmm, that is exactly what I did with the membership stuff, that was clear to me because I simply created an IMembershipService and the actual implementation of it calls those static methods for me. With this I am a little less sure there are two things that create confusion for me. 1) some methods are static others are not and two, I am inheriting from ProfileBase which has the same issue while ProfileBase.Save() can be mocked ProfileBase.Create() cannot. Hmm, I may have to mess with it but I see get the idea.